# Проблемы с созданием обработчика нажатий клавиш

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, keypressevent

Создаю окно настроек, состоящее из `label`-ов, в которых записано на какую кнопку стоит бинд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии мышкой на `label` он выделялся и при нажатии на любую кнопку клавиатуры в `label` записывалось это значение. 
Т.е. например при нажатии на кнопку **`alt`**, у выделенного `label`'а  менялся текст на **`alt`**, и при выборе другого `label`'a с предыдущего снималось выделение.

Вот код:

```
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.avtoebt.installEventFilter(self)
        self.fastbybt.installEventFilter(self)
        self.fastlvbt.installEventFilter(self)
        self.avote2bt.installEventFilter(self)
        self.scanbt.installEventFilter(self)
        self.set.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == 2 and source is not self.set:
            #выделяет рамкой выбранный label
            source.setStyleSheet("""background: #23272A;
                                        border-style: solid;
                                        border-width: 2px;
                                        border-color: #9900ff;
                                        font-family: Impact;
                                        font-style: bold;
                                        font-weight: normal;
                                        font-size: 15px;
                                        line-height: 58px;
                                        text-align: center;
                                        color: #FFFFFF;""")

            #как-то отловить нажатую клавишу
            source.setText(key)

        return False

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = mywindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yant, то что вы предоставили, не является минимально-воспроизводимым примером.
Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимым примером.

То что вы хотите сделать, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


# -----------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv  <------------- ???
#class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
# --------------------> vvvv  <------------------------------------- ???
#    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                 #, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.сentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.сentralWidget.setObjectName("сentralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.сentralWidget)
        
        self.avtoebt = QLabel()
        self.avtoebt.setObjectName('avtoebt')
        self.avtoebt.setStyleSheet("background: #E79E4F;") 
        self.avtoebt.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.fastbybt = QLabel()  
        self.fastbybt.setObjectName('fastbybt')        
        self.fastbybt.setStyleSheet("background: #E79E4F;")
        self.fastbybt.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.fastlvbt = QLabel()  
        self.fastlvbt.setObjectName('fastlvbt')        
        self.fastlvbt.setStyleSheet("background: #E79E4F;")
        self.fastlvbt.installEventFilter(self)        

        self.avote2bt = QLabel()  
        self.avote2bt.setObjectName('avote2bt')        
        self.avote2bt.setStyleSheet("background: #E79E4F;")
        self.avote2bt.installEventFilter(self)      

        self.scanbt = QLabel()  
        self.scanbt.setObjectName('scanbt')        
        self.scanbt.setStyleSheet("background: #E79E4F;")
        self.scanbt.installEventFilter(self)  
        
        self.set = QLabel('SET')  
        self.set.setObjectName('set')        
        self.set.setStyleSheet("background: #A05344;")
        self.set.installEventFilter(self) 
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.сentralWidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.avtoebt, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.fastbybt, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.fastlvbt, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.avote2bt, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.scanbt, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.set, 2, 1)
 
        self.labels = {
            self.avtoebt: False,
            self.fastbybt: False,
            self.fastlvbt: False,
            self.avote2bt: False,
            self.scanbt: False,
            self.set: False,
        }
        self.label_selected = None

        self.keymap = {}
        for key, value in vars(Qt).items():
            if isinstance(value, Qt.Key):
                self.keymap[value] = key.partition('_')[2]

        self.modmap = {
            Qt.ControlModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_Control],
            Qt.AltModifier:     self.keymap[Qt.Key_Alt],
            Qt.ShiftModifier:   self.keymap[Qt.Key_Shift],
            Qt.MetaModifier:    self.keymap[Qt.Key_Meta],
            Qt.GroupSwitchModifier: self.keymap[Qt.Key_AltGr],
            Qt.KeypadModifier:  self.keymap[Qt.Key_NumLock],
        }

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == 2 and source is not self.set:
            for label in self.labels:
                if source is label:
                    label.setStyleSheet(f"""
                        #{label.objectName()} {{
                            background: #23272A;
                            border-style: solid;
                            border-width: 2px;
                            border-color: #9900ff;
                            font-family: Impact;
                            font-style: bold;
                            font-weight: normal;
                            font-size: 15px;
                            line-height: 58px;
                            text-align: center;
                            color: #FFFFFF;
                         }}                           
                    """)
                    self.label_selected = label
                elif label is not self.set:                
                    label.setStyleSheet(f"""
                        #{label.objectName()} {{
                            background: #E79E4F;
                        }}                           
                     """)        
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def keyevent_to_string(self, event):
        sequence = []
        for modifier, text in self.modmap.items():
            if event.modifiers() & modifier:
                sequence.append(text)
        key = self.keymap.get(event.key(), event.text())
        if key not in sequence:
            sequence.append(key)
        return '+'.join(sequence)

    # отловить нажатую клавишу        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event): 
        #print(self.keyevent_to_string(event))
        if self.label_selected:
            self.label_selected.setText(self.keyevent_to_string(event))
        
        super().keyPressEvent(event)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MyWindow()
    w.resize(200, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]